# Sqlite3 gem for Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I wanna create myApp using command

> rails new myApp

but it gives an error:

> Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions
>   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb checking for sqlite3.h... no sqlite3.h is
>   missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal' or 'yum install
>   sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the location
>   where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>       --with-opt-dir
>       --without-opt-dir
>       --with-opt-include
>       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>       --with-opt-lib
>       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>       --with-make-prog
>       --without-make-prog
>       --srcdir=.
>       --curdir
>       --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
>       --with-sqlite3-dir
>       --without-sqlite3-dir
>       --with-sqlite3-include
>       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>       --with-sqlite3-lib
>       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
>       --enable-local
>       --disable-local
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out An
>   error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.4), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.4'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have the development headers for SQLite3 installed.

For example:

On Ubuntu, you can use `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

On Mac with homebrew installed: `brew install sqlite`.

Answer (score 3):

I've found it pretty helpful to run this command whenever I install rails anew on Ubuntu. This normally takes care of the super common zlib and sqlite3 errors.

/usr/bin/apt-get install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but in Windows.
I found only two solutions for now
1* After the project creation fail, enter in its folder and modify the Gemfile.
Change the line
`gem 'sqlite3',  '1.3.11'`
by one of these bellow:

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby"

gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"

gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

And run again the `bundle install` command for this project

The second solution I found was downloading the gem from https://rubygems.org/ and saving it locally to install from file, first, you've to install mingw (but only for Windows)

```
C:\Sites>ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn
C:\Sites>gem install --local C:\sqlite3-1.4.0.gem
```

I've tried some others solutions but these two were the only ones worked for me.

https://mycodeissuesandfixes.blogspot.com/2019/02/ruby-on-rails-issue-about-sqlite-3-gem.html
Those are others fixes but I don't know if they're going to help you in Linux.
Hope it helps!! I've been trying for 5 days completes until I found something that works with this error of sqlite 3 gem